# Class for an Activity set up in the AndroidManifest cannot be found

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I defined following `activity` and `intent filter` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:label="Test.SampleApp">    
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                  android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Then I have an `Activity` set up as:

```
namespace Test.SampleApp
{
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
              //....
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I start the application, it cannot find the MainActivity class:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{Test.SampleApp/Test.SampleApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.SampleApp.MainActivity
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.SampleApp.MainActivity
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2047):        ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  162):   Force finishing activity Test.SampleApp/.MainActivity
```

I'm guessing that I'm not referring to the Activity correctly in the manifest?

I've also tried using the 'Test.SampleApp.MainActivity' as a vlue for android:name,
but then the manifest is simply invalid and cannot be parsed.

I'm using `Mono for Android`, and now I'm wondering, the names used in the `manifest`,
do they relate to the C# namespaces or to something else
that is specific to the Android platform?

Note: In the manifest I've also have `package="Test.SampleApp"`

**Update:** I added the "." in front of MainActivity but I'm still getting the exact same exception.

Comment: You miss a dot in front of MainActivity

Comment: android:name=".MainActivity. Your MainActivity should extend Activity

Comment: The MainActivity extends Activity.

Comment: remove the namespace Test.SampleApp you already have a package name under which you will have source files. Also public class MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: @Raghunandan you mean remove the package name in the manifest? Keep in mind that this is not a Java application but a C# application, things work a little different here, I'm guessing that might be the source of the problems

Comment: might be i am not familiar with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback (link) from @Triode I managed to figure it out:

The manifest in the sample application on github:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="mono.actionbarsherlocktest">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:label="Mono.ActionbarsherlockTest">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The package name here is `lower case` whereas my package name contained capitals.
Changing the package name to `test.sampleapp` 
and leaving everything else untouched solved the issue.

I hope this will help other monodroid users one day.

Comment: You can accept your answer, it may be useful for some others :)

Comment: I know... but only in 2 days :p

Answer (score 0):

In general, *do not* write XML fragments for C#-provided activities. Instead, use [custom attributes](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml) and let the build system worry about it for you.

```
namespace NamespaceName {

    [Activity(
            LaunchMode=Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
            StateNotNeeded=true)]
    [IntentFilter (new[]{Android.Content.Intent.ActionMain},
            Categories=new[]{Android.Content.Intent.CategoryHome, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault})]
    public class MainActivity : Activity {
       // ...
    }
}
```

The build system will generate the `<activity/>` element and use fully-qualified type names:

```
<activity android:name="namespacename.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

There are typically only two reasons to use XML fragments and not custom attributes:

1. The type doesn't exist in C#, e.g. your `.apk` contains Java activities.
2. You need to use XML attributes/elements that haven't been exposed via custom attributes.

Comment: Thnx, I'll give this a try. The capitals in the name might still cause a problem though so if your answer works (and I'm sure it will) then I'll add that info to your answer and mark it as the answer